# Why isn't localhost resolving but other host entries are?

Tags: windows, windows-7, proxy, google-chrome

I have a Windows 7 machine that I am working on right now and am having trouble connecting to a local server that is bound to `0.0.0.0:1337`

On all the other machines that run this configuration it works fine.

The machine connects to the internet via a proxy configured in the windows Internet Options settings. I currently have the checkbox ticked that says "Bypass proxy for local addresses"

Once I have the service running I am attempting to load it via Chrome. Normally `http://127.0.0.1:1337` will work, but it appears that it is trying to resolve through the proxy, the same goes if I try `http://localhost:1337`.

For testing purposes I added `127.0.0.1 appname` to the hosts file. If I open chrome and load `http://appname:1337` it works.

This problem doesn't make any sense to me. What could be causing this?

Edit: If I attempt to load `http://localhost` without the port number it appears to resolve locally, but if I try to load `http://localhost:1337` it attempts to resolve through the proxy.

Update:
I can load the application in IE but not Chrome. Chrome is trying to send it through the proxy. I need it to load in Chrome as the application is in NW.js

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the port used. Chrome uses Internet Explorer's proxy settings. Add the the server to the "Exceptions" list as shown on the screenshot below.

If that doesn't work, please include a screenshot of your current proxy settings so we can get a better idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by explicitly setting `127.0.0.1 localhost` in the hosts file then clearing Chrome's cache.

After this the page started loading as expected.

I believe this was an isolated incident pertaining to the specific proxy server that the computer is connected through.